# What series of events could lead to the collapse of society and the rise of gangs?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-reality

Let me pitch you a setting... The year is 2017 and economic unreast is everywhere and a gang by the name of "Fukdahrooles" is trying to cause societal collapse.

My question being... how could Fukdahrooles cause the collapse of society and make America a free-for-all brawl for terrority

Note: here are the limitations.

1: The only source of income they have is the Drug Trade and odd jobs.

2: they are widely hated and are considered a Terrorist Organization (like ISIS).

3: THEY DON'T HAVE ACCESS TO NUCLEAR WEAPONS.

my question is... How could Fukdahrooles cause societal collapse in the easiest way possible?

Comment: You've got a fairly big problem, in that they can (and to some degree have) caused collapse in the inner cities.  Move out of them into more rural areas, and they become targets.

Comment: Are the Fukdahrooles a criminal organization or a revolutionary organization? No criminal organization _ever_ wants to collapse the society, because the entire point of a criminal organization is to avoid work by extracting value from the law-abiding citizens. By definition, criminals are _few_, otherwise the criminal life-style becomes too dificult to sustain: how many drug dealers are needed for one thousand citizens? Better make them revolutionaries. And better choose another country; the USA is very rich, very powerful and very ruthless.

Comment: revolutionary organization

Comment: Use social media to make people distrust the police. Attack the police. Via social media make a response further reason to distrust the police. Attack police... repeat this cycle until the police retire to Wyoming and the cities become Mad Max Thunderdome.

Comment: @imaichiko: Or turn your police into a bunch of bullies who regard the rest of the population as either civilians, who are to be treated with barely-concealed contempt, or  as scumbags, who can be beaten or killed given the slightest provocation.

Comment: What goals does Fukdahrooles have?  What is it trying to accomplish?   That's really a two part question, when I think about it.  The first part is what does Fukdahrooles want to do overall (think mission statement).  The second part is what advantage do they think they get by causing societal collapse.

Comment: Also, when you say "gang" that's typically a small number of individuals.  How large is this "gang?"

Comment: Anonymous mass immigration from the Middle East would export the 1400 years of gang (clan) violent societies of that region.

Answer (score 2):

Well, presumably this organization is getting a large amount of money from the err trade of illegal products. The organization would need enough money for any diabolical plans they may relay later on. So in the beginning they must stock up on a big wad of cash.

After this there is 1 question, how large is this organization. If it is large you could place many of them in important districts of economic strife and distress and rally the people (without them knowing they are part of this organization so as to not scare them away) against the government. Doing this in many regions of the country you have specified would overwhelm the government due to the scale and complications of the government.

If the organization has a small amount of recruits then they could establish a massive cyber attack against governmental organizations that control money (such as the stock market) and create a economic crisis and make the people even madder at the government, attack it, and create a civil strife.

Or you can use a combination of the two. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: it does @abc1234 , it really does

Comment: What is «err trade»?

Comment: I mean the drug trade, Idk I feel uncomfortable saying that word for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

The gang is trying to **collapse** the society? That sounds unrealistic. Good villains have better goals, at least from their own viewpoint.

Say the gang is actually trying to **reshape** the society to put themselves on top of the ladder and everyone else at the bottom. A cynic would say that governments are actually protection rackets with a long tradition and a good PR department. I don't think that's the case for genuinely democratic societies, but there is a large gray area between good and evil.

Having said that, the plans of the gang might well lead to widespread collapse, because they take more than they can digest, but that's an accident. Basically they want to become the new government. A classic [insurgency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insurgency).

- Reduce the ability of the old government to function. Attack teachers, tax collectors, police.
- When the economy is depressed and law and order breaks down, introduce welfare payments and police services in areas under their control.
- Courts and tax collectors come later.

This free for all you asked for comes if the gang has damaged the old government in *most* areas and only replaced it in *some* areas. In the other areas other groups might take control, and the different groups fight over territory, population, and infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

The Fukdahrooles join the police forces and subvert from within. The civil population will turn against the police. Genuine police officers will develop an extreme siege mentality & go hard on the civilians. It will become self-sustaining, right up until the collapse.

The Fukdahrooles' top echelon joins the economic, social and political upper class. They've got the money and new money is always welcome. They lobby for tougher laws to keep the unruly civilians in their place. Slash funding to social welfare education, health, public transport, and urban renewal programs Civilian unrest will increase.

The Fukdahrooles organize civilian resistance to harsh policing, cuts to social spending, and the growing super-rich skimming the cream off the top of the society. They will issue guns and weapons to the proles. Organize street gangs of dispossessed children, teenagers, and the chronically unemployed.

Rinse, repeat until the collapse.

Answer (score 0):

A government can't really function without the support of its people. I'm sure back before the communist revolution in Russia, nobody thought that some small extremist political group would ever have the power to overthrow a dynasty that's been ruling for centuries.

One way for the government to completely collapse is for the economy and general standard of living to be so horrible that a significant portion of the population overthrows the government.

But as others have mentioned, there's no way for Fukdahrooles to collapse a government unless they're some sort of revolutionary force. The only other way that it's possible is if theyre like a whole bunch of spies placed in America by other countries to overthrow the country from within. Like they're just regular looking citizens that use terrorist threats and assassinations to shake the trust of the American people. But I theorize that even if the government becomes destabilized, Fukdarooles will still have to convince the majority population that what they're doing is ok, lest homebrewed resistance cells also destabilize Fukdarooles.

Answer (score 0):

While this could be considered opinion based as you're looking for the "best/easiest" way to collapse society in the United States, one of the easiest ways would be to put road blocks on major highways or destroy them entirely.  Disrupt the supply chain long enough and society will eventually collapse.  With the large, spread-out population of the US, people forget how easily it would be for panic to set in without regular food shipments to supermarkets.  Yeah, people could get by on what they have for a week or two.  But, if the gang was able to disrupt a few major cities long enough, the chaos would spread (think about your local Wal-Mart right before a big storm is about to hit, there is nothing left on the shelves).  I'd give it a month or 2 before things got really primitive.  Although you'd need some way to account for the military presence/national guard which would step in.

Perhaps if the gang blew up all major highways, or at least put large enough holes in them to prevent trucks from travelling and then they had checkpoints on freeways.  Using guerilla tactics they could hit and run supply trucks on the remaining roadways, thus preventing almost all but air shipments from getting in.  Air shipments would run out of fuel without resupply so even those would quickly become more sparse and couldn't hope to supply even a medium size city.